# Finding the kth-smallest element in union of sorted arrays

Tags: python, algorithm

I was studying the article on finding the kth-smallest element in the union of two sorted arrays at [leetcode](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/01/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-union-of.html). I don't think that the algorithm is correct. There is this line: **We make an observation that when Ai < Bj, then it must be true that Ai < Bj-1. On the other hand, if Bj < Ai, then Bj < Ai-1.**. How can it be true for any `i` and `j`?

And secondly, this line also baffles me: **We try to approach this tricky problem by comparing middle elements of A and B, which we identify as Ai and Bj. If Ai is between Bj and Bj-1, we have just found the i+j+1 smallest element**, although it comes out to be true. Can anyone explain the reason? I really want to understand the algo, I have done it by merging the arrays, but that takes `O(N)` time, compared to `O(log N)` time here.

Comment: "union of sorted array", sounds like the `merge` part of `merge sort`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: i think the idea is you get two sorted arrays and you find the kth smallest without merging them, thus taking `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: Exactly. That is the common method of doing this problem, but it yields `O(N)` time, compared to `O(log N)` time in the linked article algo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We make an observation that when `Ai < Bj`, then it must be true that `Ai < Bj-1`. On the other hand, if `Bj < Ai`, then `Bj < Ai-1`.. How can it be true for any `i` and `j`?

It isn't true for all pairs of `i` and `j`. The article considers a special situation.

First, it is assumed that there are no duplicates, not even in the form of common elements of `A` and `B`. Second, the conclusion that

```
Ai < Bj ==> Ai < Bj-1,   resp.  Bj < Ai ==> Bj < Ai-1
```

is made under the condition that **neither** of

```
Bj-1 < Ai < Bj  resp. Ai-1 < Bj < Ai
```

holds. So by excluding these configurations, `Ai < Bj ==> Ai <= Bj-1` and `Bj < Ai ==> Bj <= Ai-1` follow immediately, and the strict inequalities then follow by the assumption that no duplicates exist.

> We try to approach this tricky problem by comparing middle elements of A and B, which we identify as Ai and Bj. If Ai is between Bj and Bj-1, we have just found the i+j+1 smallest element

In array `B`, there are `j` elements smaller than `Bj`, and in array `A`, there are `i` elements smaller than `Ai` (indices start at 0). So if `Bj-1 < Ai < Bj`, both arrays together contain exactly `j + i` elements that are smaller than `Ai`.

#### What changes if there are duplicates?

Not much.

We still consider the situation where `i + j = k-1`. Let us assume that `Ai <= Bj`.

1. What if `Ai = Bj`?
2. What if `Ai < Bj`?

In case 1., let `m` be the smallest index such that `Am = Ai`, and `n` the smallest index such that `Bn = Bj`. Then in both arrays together, there are exactly `m + n <= i + j = k-1` elements strictly smaller than `Ai`, and at least `(i+1) + (j+1) = (k+1)` elements not larger than `Ai`. Hence the k-th smallest element is equal to `Ai`.

For 2., we have three cases to consider, a) `Bj-1 < Ai`, b) `Bj-1 = Ai`, c) `Bj-1 > Ai`.

In case a), we have `j` elements in `B` that are not larger than `Ai`, and they are all strictly smaller, and we have `m <= i` elements in `A` that are strictly smaller than `Ai` (`m` as above) and an unkown number, but at least `i-m+1` elements equal to `Ai`. So there are exactly `j + m <= j + i = k-1` elements in both arrays together that are strictly smaller than `Ai`, and at least `j + m + (i-m+1) = j+i+1 = k` elements not larger than `Ai`, hence the k-th smallest element of both arrays together is equal to `Ai`.

In case b), the same reasoning shows that the k-th smallest element of both arrays together is equal to `Ai`.

In the remaining case, `Ai < Bj-1`, things become hardly more complicated. Array `B` contains at least `j` elements not larger than `Bj-1`, and array `A` contains at least `i+1` elements strictly smaller than `Bj-1`, hence the k-th smallest element of both arrays together is at most as large as `Bj-1`. But it cannot be smaller than `Ai` (`B` contains at most `j-1` elements smaller than `Ai`, so both arrays together contain at most `i + (j-1) = k-2` elements smaller than `Ai`).

So we can still discard the part below `Ai` from the array `A` and the part above `Bj-1` from the array `B` and proceed as without duplicates.

All that changed was that a few strict inequalities had to be replaced with weak inequalities.

The code (would be more efficient if starting indices and lengths were passed instead of slicing, but slicing yields shorter code):

```
def kthsmallest(A, B, k):
    if k < 1:
        return None
    a_len, b_len = len(A), len(B)
    if a_len == 0:
        return B[k-1] # let it die if B is too short, I don't care
    if b_len == 0:
        return A[k-1] # see above
    # Handle edge case: if k == a_len + b_len, we would
    # get an out-of-bounds index, since i + j <= a_len+b_len - 2
    # for valid indices i and j
    if a_len + b_len == k:
        if A[-1] < B[-1]:
            return B[-1]
        else:
            return A[-1]
    # Find indices i and j approximately proportional to len(A)/len(B)
    i = (a_len*(k-1)) // (a_len+b_len)
    j = k-1-i
    # Make sure the indices are valid, in unfortunate cases,
    # j could be set to b_len by the above
    if j >= b_len:
        j = b_len-1
        i = k-1-j
    if A[i] <= B[j]:
        if j == 0 or B[j-1] <= A[i]:
            return A[i]
        # A[i] < B[j-1] <= B[j]
        return kthsmallest(A[i:], B[:j], k-i)
    # B[j] < A[i], symmetrical to A[i] < B[j]
    if i == 0 or A[i-1] <= B[j]:
        return B[j]
    # B[j] < A[i-1]
    return kthsmallest(A[:i], B[j:], k-j)
```

Comment: How will the algo be affected if the arrays contain duplicate elements themselves, as well as duplicates between themselves (these common duplicates may themselves duplicate within the individual arrays)?

Comment: It looks like pretty complicated. I am having great difficulty in following the logic, even though you explain it pretty lucidly. Can you suggest a different algorithm? Do you think it is very complicated, or is it that I am just too dumb to get it?

Comment: I've added code, does that look too complicated (in connection with the explanation)?

Comment: It will take *some* time to get that into my head. My fault, I am just beginning to get accustomed to complex algorithms.

Comment: And yes, slicing will add additional overhead, hence it should be done with indexes. This is complicated enough, God only knows what it will become if the slicing is replaced by indexes!

Answer (score 7):

You're interpreting these statements in isolation, but they build on one another. Here's the text that (I think) you're referring to:

> Maintaining the invariant
>       i + j = k – 1,
>   If Bj-1 < Ai < Bj, then Ai must be the k-th smallest,
>   or else if Ai-1 < Bj < Ai, then Bj must be the k-th smallest.
>   If one of the above conditions are satisfied, we are done. If not, we will use i and j as the pivot index to subdivide the arrays. But how? Which portion should we discard? How about Ai and Bj itself?
>
> We make an observation that when Ai < Bj, then it must be true that Ai < Bj-1. On the other hand, if Bj < Ai, then Bj < Ai-1. Why?

Breaking this down into sub-propositions yields the following interpretation (keeping in mind that indexing starts from `0`, but that `A0` is the *first* smallest item, and `A1` is the *second* smallest item, and so on):

1. `i + j = k - 1` (invariant, by definition)
2. Posit that `Bj-1 < Ai < Bj`. Then `Ai` must be the `k`th smallest. This is because `Ai` is greater than `i` items in `A` and is greater than `j` items in `B`. So it's greater than a total of `i + j = k - 1` items. That means its *index* in a merged `A|B` list would be `k - 1`, and so it would be the `k`th item in that list.
3. Posit that `Ai-1 < Bj < Ai`. Then `Bj` must be the `k`th smallest, by the same line of reasoning in 2.
4. Now posit that both (a) `Bj-1 < Ai < Bj` and (b) `Ai-1 < Bj < Ai` are *false*. Then it follows quite obviously that if `Ai < Bj` then `A1 < Bj-1`, because otherwise (a) would be true. And likewise, if `Bj < Ai` then `Bj < Ai-1`, because otherwise, (b) would be true.

I'm taking you at your word that you want an explanation of *these statements* rather than of the algorithm as a whole. (But I'll say more if you like.)

Note also that, as [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555973/577088)'s answer reminds me, the above reasoning only holds if there are no duplicates; call that proposition 0.

Comment: Wait wait, let me see if that suffices! Thanks, by the way!

Comment: But if the two assertions in 4 are wrong, then it is also possible that instead of `Ai < Bj` and `A1 < Bj-1`, `Ai > Bj`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The point is simply that if (a) and (b) above are both false, then Ai is either above both Bj and Bj-1 or below both; and the same for Bj.

Comment: So if both are possible, how come the algo rides on the fact that only one is possible?

Comment: I don't see how it rides on the fact that only one is possible. I suppose it rides on the fact that if `Ai < Bj-1 < Bj`, then `Bj > Ai > Ai-1`, and vice versa. So in other words both are possible, but if one holds for Ai, then the other holds for Bj.